# Cron jobs not working in Homestead

Tags: linux, laravel, ubuntu, cron, homestead

I'm running Homestead on my win8 laptop, and my Cron doesn't seem to be running at all. I'm trying to get scheduled jobs to work for Laravel but I'm stuck on getting Cron to run at all at the moment.

This is my crontab, just something simple to try debugging it.

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ crontab -l
* * * * * date >> /home/vagrant/Code/CRONTRACK.txt
* * * * * /usr/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /home/vagrant/Code/laravel_cron_output.txt
```

Does this look correct when using crontab -e to try edit my crontab?

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ crontab -e
143
```

Now when i try to check my system to see if cron ran anything

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ grep CRON /var/log/syslog
Dec  3 19:41:01 homestead CRON[3628]: (vagrant) CMD (date >> /home/vagrant/Code/CRONTRACK.txt^M)
Dec  3 19:41:01 homestead CRON[3629]: (vagrant) CMD (/usr/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /home/vagrant/Code/laravel_cron_output.txt^M)
Dec  3 19:41:01 homestead CRON[3627]: (vagrant) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x004b, #012)
Dec  3 19:41:01 homestead CRON[3626]: (vagrant) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x004b, #012)
Dec  3 19:42:01 homestead CRON[3635]: (vagrant) CMD (date >> /home/vagrant/Code/CRONTRACK.txt^M)
Dec  3 19:42:01 homestead CRON[3636]: (vagrant) CMD (/usr/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /home/vagrant/Code/laravel_cron_output.txt^M)
Dec  3 19:42:01 homestead CRON[3634]: (vagrant) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x004b, #012)
Dec  3 19:42:01 homestead CRON[3633]: (vagrant) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x004b, #012)
Dec  3 19:43:01 homestead CRON[3642]: (vagrant) CMD (date >> /home/vagrant/Code/CRONTRACK.txt^M)
Dec  3 19:43:01 homestead CRON[3643]: (vagrant) CMD (/usr/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /home/vagrant/Code/laravel_cron_output.txt^M)
Dec  3 19:43:01 homestead CRON[3641]: (vagrant) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x004b, #012)
Dec  3 19:43:01 homestead CRON[3640]: (vagrant) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x004b, #012)
Dec  3 19:44:01 homestead CRON[3649]: (vagrant) CMD (date >> /home/vagrant/Code/CRONTRACK.txt^M)
Dec  3 19:44:01 homestead CRON[3650]: (vagrant) CMD (/usr/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /home/vagrant/Code/laravel_cron_output.txt^M)
Dec  3 19:44:01 homestead CRON[3648]: (vagrant) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x004b, #012)
Dec  3 19:44:01 homestead CRON[3647]: (vagrant) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x004b, #012)
Dec  3 19:45:01 homestead CRON[3656]: (vagrant) CMD (date >> /home/vagrant/Code/CRONTRACK.txt^M)
Dec  3 19:45:01 homestead CRON[3657]: (vagrant) CMD (/usr/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /home/vagrant/Code/laravel_cron_output.txt^M)
Dec  3 19:45:01 homestead CRON[3655]: (vagrant) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x004b, #012)
Dec  3 19:45:01 homestead CRON[3654]: (vagrant) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x004b, #012)
```

Seems like it worked, but I can't find my txt file that I piped the output to!

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ cat /home/vagrant/Code/CRONTRACK.txt^M
cat: /home/vagrant/Code/CRONTRACK.txt^M: No such file or directory
vagrant@homestead:~$ cat /home/vagrant/Code/CRONTRACK.txt
cat: /home/vagrant/Code/CRONTRACK.txt: No such file or directory
vagrant@homestead:~$ ll /home/vagrant/Code/
total 82
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  4096 Dec  3 18:59 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 vagrant vagrant  4096 Dec  3 19:31 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   153 Dec  3 19:24 crontab.txt*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant 70449 Oct 15 20:44 memcached-2.2.0.tgz*
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant  4096 Oct 20 19:05 sample/
vagrant@homestead:~$
```

And running the commands I gave Cron directly in terminal works perfectly fine!

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ date >> /home/vagrant/Code/CRONTRACK.txt^M
vagrant@homestead:~$ cat /home/vagrant/Code/CRONTRACK.txt^M
Thu Dec  3 19:53:06 UTC 2015
```

Also, where does the ^M come from? It doesn't show up in crontab -l.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved.
I made my crontab file in notepad, which appends carriage return which linux doesn't like with my new line.

```
crontab -l
```

doesnt reveal the CR (I don't understand why not if its such an issue for linux!?!?).

So it took using notepad++ and sublime text to find and fix the issue.